# Querying from sql with dynamic model name and fields in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm new in Django and struggling with some dynamic solutions. I am trying to make an application that user can create table from UI and import data into this table from flat file and then user can be able to browse that data by clicking url(for example, if user create a table for employee, then user should be able to have a url like this for employee : localhost/employee). I will work on import part later but for now, i am trying to find a solution to browse data. And below query is almost do this. But i am not able to use alias instead of column names. Is there any way to build something like that dynamic?

```
def employee(request):
    entries = Employee.objects.annotate(First Name=F('FirstName')). only('FirstName','Email')
    print(entries)
    return render_to_response('employee.html',{'employees': serializers.serialize("json",entries, fields=('First Name','Email'))})
```

Above query give me below result. I have only email information here. So there is no First Name because annotate is not working.

```
[{"model": "client.employee", "pk": 1, "fields": {"Email":"employe1@gmail.com"}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5711), django does not allow serializing non-model fields. So, you need to override the serailizer, so you can try like this:

Write the custom serializer(which will override original json serializer) in a separate file i.e **custom_serializer.py**

```
# custom_serializer.py

from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field == 'pk' or field=='id':  # primary key field
                continue
            elif field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    self._current[field] = getattr(obj, field)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
```

inside the views, import that CustomSerializer and use it. for example

```
# inside views.py
from .custom_serializer import CustomSerializer

def employee(request):
   ...
   json_data = CustomSerializer().serialize(
      entries
      fields = (
        'First_Name',
        'email'
      )
```

Comment: I didn't understand how override while have to use exact table field name in `fields={'FirstName','Email'} ` part. Because it is ignoring that field when use alias. How can i tell replace 'FirstName' with 'First Name' or 'Email' with 'Email Address'

Comment: Yes it is working now. One more thing, is it possible to use space and special characters in alias? Sample 'First Name' with spaces and 'Avg %' with special characters. I am asking because when i use `.annotate(First Name=F('FirstName'))` like this it failing because of space and %

Comment: I don't think so. It is a variable name, and python syntax does not support space. But you can put underscore here.

Comment: In fact, i will get alias and field names from ColumnDefinition table for each data tables. For example for Employee table, i will have some rows like this : `ID=1,FieldName=FirstName, AliasName=First Name, DataType=Varchar, DataLength=255`. So my question, instead of sending alias from `def Employee()` can i query and get alias name from ColumnDefinition table in `CustomSerializer` function and use alias with spaces there?

Comment: I don't think so